# React navigation tabBarVisible: false not working for StackNavigator inside TabNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am totally confused to achieve something like below, this is working fine but can't hide tab bar for EditPage and PageTwo

- Login
- SignUp
- TabNavigator(TabNavigator)

  - FirstTab
  - SecondTab(StackNavigator)

    - ListPage
    - EditPage
  - ThirdTab(StackNavigator)

    - PageOne
    - PageTwo
  - Settings

Below is my configuration for it.

```js
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
//Other required imports here

const SignedOut = createStackNavigator({
  Signup: { screen : Signup},
  Login: { screen : Login}
});

const SignedIn = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Dashboard: {
      screen: Dashboard
    },
    Rewards: {
      screen: createStackNavigator({
        Rewards:{
          screen: Rewards,
          navigationOptions:{
            header:null
          }
        },
        AddReward:{
          screen: AddReward,
          navigationOptions:{
            header:null,
            tabBarVisible: false
          }
        }
      })
    },
    Activities: {
      screen: createStackNavigator({
        Rewards:{
          screen: Activities,
          navigationOptions:{
            header:null
          }
        },
        NewActivity:{
          screen: NewActivity,
          navigationOptions:{
            header:null,
            tabBarVisible: false
          }
        }
      })
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: Settings
    }
},{
  tabBarComponent: ({navigation}) => <FooterComponent navigation={navigation} />,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  animationEnabled: false,
  swipeEnabled: false
});

export const createRootNavigator = (signedIn) => {
    return createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            SignedIn: {
                screen: SignedIn
            },
            SignedOut: {
                screen: SignedOut
            }
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: (signedIn) ? "SignedIn" :"SignedOut",
            headerMode: 'none'
        }
    );
};
```

**Problems**

- I can't hide tab bar for **AddReward** and **NewActivity**
- `tabBarVisible: false` not working for StackNavigator inside TabNavigator

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use one StackNavigator with all your stacks, and set the TabNavigator as default route :

- SwitchNavigator

  - Login
  - SignUp
  - StackNavigator

    - TabNavigator

      - FirstTab
      - ListPage
      - Settings
    - EditPage
    - PageTwo

Comment: Thanks this is working as expected, i am testing more if have any issue remain.

Comment: Switching between tabs have some delay like 1 second, what should be reason for it ?

Comment: I'm glad it worked, please validate my answer if it matches tour requirement.

Comment: Navigators can be slow because of remote js debugging, you can disable it this way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50531400/5359812

Comment: Thanks trying disable js debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your screens (Rewards and AddRewards are inside a Stack Navigator)

OLD:

```
 Rewards: {
          screen: createStackNavigator({
            Rewards:{
              screen: Rewards,
              navigationOptions:{
                header:null
              }
            },
            AddReward:{
              screen: AddReward,
              navigationOptions:{
                header:null,
                tabBarVisible: false
              }
            }
          })
        }
```

FIX:

```
    Rewards: {
          screen: createStackNavigator({
            Rewards,
            AddReward,
          }),
          navigationOptions:{
            header:null,
            tabBarVisible: false
          }
        }
```

Comment: @Marianlordache I want tab bar visible for **Rewards** and don't visible for **AddRewards**. Your suggestion is hide tab bar for Rewards too. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

More details are found on the official document, Tested working with v 3.0.9:

[A tab navigator contains a stack and you want to hide the tab bar on specific screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-tab-navigator-contains-a-stack-and-you-want-to-hide-the-tab-bar-on-specific-screens)

**modified code from:**

```
const FeedStack = createStackNavigator({
  FeedHome: FeedScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen,
});

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: FeedStack,
  Profile: ProfileScreen,
});

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Auth: AuthScreen,
  Home: TabNavigator,
});
```

**To:**

```
const FeedStack = createStackNavigator({
  FeedHome: FeedScreen,
  /* any other route you want to render under the tab bar */
});

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: FeedStack,
  Profile: ProfileScreen,
});

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs: TabNavigator,
  Details: DetailsScreen,
  /* any other route you want to render above the tab bar */
});

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Auth: AuthScreen,
  Home: HomeStack,
});
```

**Additionally, in this example, FeedScreen will have two headers: one from FeedStack and the other from HomeStack. To solve this problem, one solution is to set default header height of HomeStack to 0 and override height in DetailsScreen. Below is an example:**

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: TabNavigator,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
    /* any other route you want to render above the tab bar */
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: { height: 0, },
      headerForceInset: { top: 'never', bottom: 'never' },
    },
  },
);
```

**The other solution is:**

[A stack contains a tab navigator and you want to set the title on the stack header](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-stack-contains-a-tab-navigator-and-you-want-to-set-the-title-on-the-stack-header)

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: FeedStack,
  Profile: ProfileStack,
});

TabNavigator.navigationOptions = {
  // Hide the header from AppNavigator stack
  header: null,
};
```

Well, for me these solutions are kind of tricky.
Anyway, it works.

Answer (score 0):

***React Navigation v5:***

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sH6OqX6ANeE

This solved my problem.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

In Tab.Screen options, just use the tabBarStyle: {display: none}.

Ex:

```
<Tab.Screen name="About Screen" component={TabAboutScreen} 
       options={{
                tabBarLabel:"About",
                tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' },
            
        }}    
/>
```